# accessing services outside kubernetes

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, rancher

I want to access external services/APIs

like calling wikipedia so I need port 80 http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=bee&limit=1&format=json

my app is in a pod inside a container and I exposed port 8000 and binded it 300 in the service type loadbalncer  .

Also accessing external databases hosted outside kubernetes  like mysql so I need  port 3306 how that can be done .

those are both the deployment and service files

https://github.com/hadyrashwan/request-wiki/blob/feature/open-internal-80/wiki-request-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: request-wiki-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: request-wiki
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: request-wiki
        image: hadyrashwan/request-wiki:0.0.4
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        - containerPort: 80
```

https://github.com/hadyrashwan/request-wiki/blob/feature/open-internal-80/wiki-request-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: request-wiki
  name:  request-wiki-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: request-wiki
  ports:
#  - name: app
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
#  - name: app
#    protocol: TCP
#    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

still not using configurations/secrets or tls

I'm using rancher with 2 hosts for kubernetes environment one on GCP and the other on AWS

Comment: What is the question? You can't access external service from inside a pod? What error you have got?

Comment: yes { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN en.wikipedia.org:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:73:26)
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'en.wikipedia.org',
  host: 'en.wikipedia.org',
  port: 443 }

Answer (score 1):

By default, your pods will use the docker bridge of the node they are located in for egress connections.

Try to test connections from the nodes you are going to use to deploy your pods, if you can connect from the nodes, your pods should be able to do it too. This way you will be able to track any issue related to egress connections easily (check firewall rules, interfaces configured correctly, etc.).

These port options you are configuring in your yamls are for ingress traffic only.

Comment: I confirm that I'm able to get a result from ssh to the node 
h2rashwan@instance-2:~$ curl -X GET -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 8decd972-20dc-8d4b-087b-901dc7d1697f" "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&
action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow"
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"21721040": ...... also I updated the yaml file to include port 80 but still can't connect

Comment: It's not related with the port configuration in the yaml file, that is just for ingress traffic.
You can test the connectivity of your containers at node level with the outside using a basic docker called busybox: `docker pull busybox` and after that `docker run busybox sh -c "ping -c 5 en.wikipedia.org"`
If it works, your container should be able to connect and the problem will be probably in your app, if not, you have to check the docker networking.

Comment: both the busybox and my app are working from the 2 nodes  $ sudo docker run -it  -p 8000:8000 hadyrashwan/request-wiki:0.0.8

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong then you want to reach your kube service's from outside of kubernetes. 
You can use service type NodePort

> Type NodePort
>
> master will allocate a port from a flag-configured range (default:
>   30000-32767), and each Node will proxy that port (the same port number
>   on every Node) into your Service. That port will be reported in your
>   Service’s spec.ports[*].nodePort field.If you set the type field to "NodePort", the Kubernetes

you can define kube service like this

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-service"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "MyApp"
        },
        "ports": [
            {
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 80,
                "targetPort": 9376,
                "nodePort": 30061
            }
        ],
        "type": "LoadBalancer"
    },
    }
}
```

Or you can use kubectl as well

```
kubectl expose rc example-rc --type=NodePort --port=9000 --target-port=8080 --node-port=32001
```

above should work with deployment as well

so at the end if you want to reach your service then hit `anynode:nodeport`

Comment: No , I want the pod node service to be able to communicate with external world through ports like 443 80 3306