# Not able to hit a kubernetes svc end point

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

Hi all i am trying to hit kubernetes service which is running a fastapi app on it and keep getting this connection refused, any insight here would be helpful, thanks in advance

```
curl -X POST "https://file-monitoring-ms.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/api/v1/filemonitor/" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json"
-d "{}"
```

**i also tried file-monitoring-ms.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/api/v1/filemonitor/, as endpoint same connection refused** without the https

```
app.include_router(filesmonitor, prefix='/api/v1/filemonitor', tags=['filemonitor'])

...

...

@filesmonitor.post("/", status_code=201)
async def getSqsEvent
```

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: file-monitoring-ms
  name: file-monitoring-ms
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: file-monitoring-ms
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: file-monitoring-ms
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          image: file-monitoring-image:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              protocol: TCP
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: file-monitoring-ms
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: file-monitoring-ms
  labels:
    app: file-monitoring-ms
spec:
  selector:
    app: file-monitoring-ms
  ports:
    - name: http
      targetPort: 8000  # port the container accepts traffic on
      port: 8000  # port other pods use to access the Service
      protocol: TCP
```

here is the describe on the service
[image]

also here is the container saying its running and listening
[image]

Comment: might be helpful : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Comment: please replace the images in your question with text copied from your terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing services outside kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063760/accessing-services-outside-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes, there is types of service

The default one is **Cluster IP** : Which is only accessible internally inside the cluster

**Load Balancer** : Expose the service directly and openly to internet using IP.

**Node Port**: Using Node or worker node application get exposed to the internet.

**For local testing :**

```
kubectl port-forward svc/file-monitoring-ms 8081:8080
```

this will create the proxy between CLuster to local port

you can access your API now at :

```
curl http://localhost:8081
```

Your default service type of CLuster IP so service wont be accessible using the `curl` over the internet

Above command only for development purposes or to debug the things.

Local port `8081` will direct forward request to service port `8080` using the kubectl proxy.

Final answer :

If you will run another container in the same cluster and hit this URL it will work however your service is not exposed you won't be able to access the data out of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could first try figuring out whether the service is reachable inside the container by executing `kubectl exec -it <YOUR_POD_NAME> -- curl 127.0.0.1:8000` and checking the logs of the service.

If the service is reachable inside, you could then consider further whether there are some networking issues or something else.

Comment: it is reachable inside the pod like you said

Comment: If you want to visit the service outside the cluster you need to set the type of service as `NodePort` or use Ingress to handle the request. The DNS records of the service you have mentioned could only be accessed inside the cluster.

Comment: but yes i am trying to handle it within the cluster itself, i have a seperate pod with in the same namespace sending a post request to this

Comment: You could `curl` the IP address of the service in that Pod and check whether the network is connected. If it works well, `nslookup` could help you check whether DNS could be correctly resolved as the IP address of the service.

Answer (score 0):

ClusterIP type services will be only reachable inside the cluster only. If you are trying from outside the cluster use type nodePort or use an ingress.

If you are trying the curl inside your cluster itself you don't have to add the port to your URL.